# Tensorflow optimizers: loss sum vs mean

Tags: tensorflow

I'm wondering if the Tensorflow optimizers (in particular the `AdamOptimizer`) have a preference when it comes to defining a loss function as a sum or as a mean/average over a minibatch?

In general my assumption was that using the mean is preferred, because the loss does not depend with the size of the mini batches. Thus, it is easier to find a learning rate which works with any batch size.

However, Tensorflow defines e.g. [`l2_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) internally as:

```
output = sum(t ** 2) / 2
```

Does this imply that the optimizers account for the batch size internally already, i.e., they expect losses to scale linearly with the batch size? Also, what's the motivation of taking half the L2 norm from the perspective of optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here l2_loss is actually a regularization loss function. We add that inside our main loss functions inorder to prevent the parameters from over fitting. We normally divide the l2 loss by 2 inorder to make it easy when taking the gradients.

And inside any optimizer we take the average loss w.r.t batch size.

Comment: I see, the division by 2 is just there to have one less multiplication in the gradient. So to be clear: For a non-regularization use case, it's better to use `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - target))`

Comment: Well it's according to your loss function. Here the loss function you are implementing is called linear squared sum and yes it's always good to take the mean. In the previous case l2 loss we use division by two just to make it easy  when getting gradients.